# Error when training model in Colab on TPU

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to build a GAN using TensorFlow and wanted to train it on TPU. However I'm getting the error mentioned below
'Make sure the slot variables are created under the same strategy scope. This may happen if you're restoring from a checkpoint outside the scope'
I'm fairly new to TensorFlow. All my variables have been created with tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy

Comment: I'm not using any checkpoints either.

Answer (score 0):

Either you are using a model with custom layers or a recent version of TensorFlow. If so, `load_weights` must be called within the correct scope. Like this:

```
strategy = TPUStrategy(resolver)
with strategy.scope():
    model = ...
    model.compile(...)
    model.load_weights(...)
```